# Angular 2 dynamic access to template elements

Tags: angular

I have a component with a bootstrap `nav-tabs` element.
They have dynamic ids because the component is used in an `ngFor`.
The ids are given in the `OnInit` handler because they are dependent on an `@Input` object.

I have a method on the component that is attached to the `click` event of all tabs which handles a somewhat complex logic attaching scroll bars and expanding tab elements depending on the click order. In other words I need something like `addClass` and `removeClass` methods on my template elements.

There is no easy and readable way to implement that logic in the template html directly. It's too complex.

I have looked into the `@ViewChild` element but that is not applicable here, since I cannot use it dynamically in my click handler. I would need to define it on the component level but at that point my ids are not given yet.

What is the best and Angular2 way to access template elements dynamically in my click handler and add and remove classes from them?

As requested, here is the logic in my click handler. As a proof-of-concept I use `document` access but that is obviously not the way to go.

```
public toggleOverflow (id: string): void
{
    let i = this.endsWith(id, "1") ? 0 : 1;

    let anyOpen = this.tabActive[0].open || this.tabActive[1].open;
    if (!anyOpen)
    {
        document.getElementById(this.containerId).classList.remove("movie-info-overflow");
        document.getElementById(this.onTopId).classList.add("ontop");
    }

    if (!this.tabActive[i].open)
    {
        this.tabActive[i].open = true;
        this.tabActive[i].id = id;
        document.getElementById(id).classList.add("scroll");
        if (anyOpen)
        {
            // close currently open tab
            i = Math.abs(i - 1);
            this.tabActive[i].open = false;
            document.getElementById(this.tabActive[i].id).classList.remove("scroll");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.tabActive[i].open = false;
        document.getElementById(id).classList.remove("scroll");

        document.getElementById(this.containerId).classList.add("movie-info-overflow");
        document.getElementById(this.onTopId).classList.remove("ontop");
    }
}
```

The tabs only show part of the text initially in order not to cover the following elements in the list. Only when they are clicked will the full text be revealed by adding a scroll bar to the text (class `scroll`) and setting the tab high in the z-order (class `ontop`).

As you can see, I need to access not only the element that caused the `click` event but also the neighboring tab element.

The relevant part of the template:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs movie-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a [attr.href]="'#' + tabId1" data-toggle="tab" (click)="toggleOverflow(tabId1)">Description</a></li>
    <li ng-if="movie.comments.length > 0"><a [attr.href]="'#' + tabId2" data-toggle="tab" (click)="toggleOverflow(tabId2)">Comments</a></li>
</ul>
<div [attr.id]="onTopId" class="tab-content">
    <div [attr.id]="tabId1" class="tab-pane movie-tab active">
        <p class="movie-description">{{movie.description}}</p>
    </div>
    <div [attr.id]="tabId2" class="tab-pane movie-tab">
        <p class="movie-description">{{movie.comments}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. From your description I can only get a vague picture.

Comment: Where are these elements that you want to fetch. Can you please add the part of the template?

Comment: This should be quite easy to solve with `[ngClass]=".."` or `[class.scroll]="..."`. Instead of trying to access the elements and modifying them you should modify the model and use bindings in the template to get classes and styles added/removed depending on the model changes.

Comment: Thanks, Günter, you are right. It is quite easy to solve with model flags. Coming from Angular1 I am not quite used to doing things the Angular2 way yet. Having implemented the changes, I actually like it better now. If you put your suggestion in an answer I'm happy to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. I guess something like

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" #item (click)="doSomething($event, item)"></div>
```

would do what you want.
In fact the template variable is not necessary because `event.target` would allow to access the clicked element as well.